# How set a specific attribute in a JObject

Tags: c#, json

I have the next JSON:

```
{  
   "Atrrib1":"Value1",
   "Legs":[  
      {  
         "InternalAttrib1":"Value2",
         "InternalAttrib2":"Value3",
         "InternalDate":"2014-10-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      {  
         "InternalAttrib1":"Value4",
         "InternalAttrib2":"Value5",
         "InternalDate":"2014-10-01T00:00:00Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

And I have a function to set the date, if I want to change for example the "Attrib1", I made in this way:

```
public JObject FixAtribb1(JObject request)
        {
            request["Attrib1"] = "SomeValue";
            return request;
        }
```

but when I try to make the same for "InternalDate" doesn't work and create another attrib in the original JSON:

```
request[@"Legs[" + legCount + "].InternalDate"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

How can assign the value for "InternalDate" in the same way that I make for "Attrib1"?

Comment: As you are setting new "DepartureDate", how it can change "InternalDate"?

Comment: Sorry I fix that, my mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is something like this

```
request["Legs"][legCount]["InternalDate"] =DateTime.UtcNow;
```

You can even use `dynamic` keyword

```
dynamic  dyn = request;
dyn.Legs[0].InternalDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
```